# How to install Maven in RAD 8.5.1?

Tags: maven, rad

**Unable to install Maven in RAD 8.5.1 using the update site.**

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.0.20110607-2117 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.20110607-2117)
Missing requirement: m2e Marketplace 1.0.0.20110607-2117 (org.eclipse.m2e.discovery 1.0.0.20110607-2117) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.0.20110607-2117 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.20110607-2117)
To: org.eclipse.m2e.discovery [1.0.0.20110607-2117]

Comment: You can install Maven in RAD 8.5.1 only using the IBM Installation Manager. You cannot install Maven using the update site.

Answer (score 13):

It took me a bit of effort to figure this out, so here's an expanded answer:

- In the IBM Installation Manager, click "Modify".
- Find the IBM Software Delivery Platform that includes **IBM Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software 8.5**
- Click "Next" to get to the language page
- Click "Next" to get to the feature selection page
- Maven is listed under **IBM Rational Application Developer for WebSphere** -> **Collaborative development and build tools**
- Click "Next", then "Modify" and let the installation manager do its thing.

Comment: After "Modify" if it ask path (like disk 4 or 3) , you should browse path :apps\IBM\rational Application Developer\ **Version(8.*)**\RAD (which has disk folders in this dir).